# FB graph api returns short lived token instead of long lived token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get long lived token for pages which doesn't expire. To do this, I first get the long lived user access token. Once my app has that, it makes a call to get the page token using the following code:

```
var URL = "/PAGE_ID/?fields=access_token=LONG_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN";
FB.api(URL, function(response) {
}
```

The token returned is though short lived.
However, if I use the same URL and call it using the [FB Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), the token I receive is long token.

I'm not sure why the same URL will generate a short token when I call is using FB.api(){} vs. a long token when I test it using the FB Graph API Explorer.

Comment: are you sure the user token is an extended one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> var URL = "/PAGE_ID/?fields=access_token=LONG_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN";

You are not passing an access token at all here. What you are doing, is passing *one* parameter named `fields` with the value `access_token=LONG_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN`

You want to pass one parameter *named* `fields` with the *value* `access_token`, and one parameter *named* `access_token` wit the *value* `LONG_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN` - so that URL of course has to look like this:

```
var URL = "/PAGE_ID/?fields=access_token&access_token=LONG_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN";
```

Comment: Ahh, got it. Thanks!